# Rails sum query with hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hstore

I have got a table with an hstore column. What I need to do is sumarize all of the entries of a specific hstore key.

one Stat record looks like this:

```
 id: 2041,
 tenant_name: "isabela",
 totals:
 {"value1"=>"31",
 "value2"=>"21",
 "value3"=>"38",
 "value4"=>"28",
 "value5"=>"0"},
 created_at: Tue, 05 May 2015 23:31:01 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 05 May 2015 23:31:01 UTC +00:00>,
```

With totals being the hstore column.
What i would like is to find the sum of every records value1 for a specific day. 
so far i got:

```
string = [];
dates.each do |date|
  count = Stat.where(created_at: DateTime.parse(date).midnight..DateTime.parse(date).midnight + 1.day))
  string.push(count)
end
//(dates = an array of dates)
```

Does anyone have a good idea how to do this?

**update** got it to work with:

```
.sum("(totals->'value1')::integer")
```

Comment: from where `dates` are coming? Are those `dates` will be the input ?

Comment: dates is an array of dates. so for instance ["25/01/2015", "26/01/2015", "27/01/2015", "28/01/2015"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do :

```
sums = dates.map do |date|
  Stat.where(created_at: DateTime.parse(date).midnight..DateTime.parse(date).midnight + 1.day))
      .sum("totals->'value1'::integer")
end
```

`sums` now holds the summation of `value1` of all records/per day.

Comment: It didn't work our exactly like that but I got t to work, updated it in my post. thanks